# When to use or not use the Contract Scope?

Tags: smart-contract, table, architecture

Analyzing the `eosio.token` contract we see that the token stats is stored under the `SYM` scope. So if I want to read a token stat, like supply, I need to execute:

`cleos get table eosio.token EOS stats`

Replace `EOS` for any token that you create. My question is why it's architected in this way? Wouldn't be better if it was stored in the `_self` scope? Because if I run this instead:

`cleos get table eosio.token eosio.token stats`

I can have and work with a list of all created tokens under this contract and have a better vision. Actually how could I list and know all the created tokens if I don't know each `SYM` scope?

Answer (score 3):

By using the scope you can have easier fetches. Think of it like the exact index you are searching for without have to use upper/lower bounds.

If we take that same logic to a user's info we could do

`cleos get table contract username account
cleos get table contract username balance
cleos get table contract username friends`

instead of 
`cleos get table contract contract accounts -L lower -U upper`

Logically, I'm also sure this is better resource wise as it only has to check for a single record, and not iterate the set.

Comment: That makes sense. The only con that I see is that we don't have a way to list all the `usernames` in your scenario, or all the created `tokens` in mine. Is that correct?

Comment: reference table

Comment: yeah so we always need to balance performance vs storage. I don't like it because in your scenario I could have username as primary key for all the three tables and always utilize `get` instead of play with `lower` and `upper` bounds... In the end I would need to test both to check bandwith vs storage, and which approach is worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Does anyone have the definition of `scope` ?  To me, it basically looks like a way to compartmentalize data in a contract so that it only accessible within a certain space.  In the above example, the data `account` `balance` and `friends` will exist in the contract only for the matching `username` given. When a different username is given as the scope, a new `account` `balance` and `friends` will exist for that usernames scope.

But also note that in that example `account` `balance` and `friends` are probably multi_index containers themselves and each can contain multiple data objects within them.  So you could have multiple `friends` objects in your `username` scope.

In the token example, each account is used as the scope for the account balance.  That way you have a container called `accounts` which holds multiple account objects, where each account object holds your balance for that given token symbol.  This way when you query a users account using their scope you will get a list of all the tokens (every ticker symbol) that users has an account with a balance for.

I think they do it this way to keep all the token symbols that a users has in one place. Whereas if you scoped it to the contract itself, you would have to redesign the two containers `accounts` and `currencys_stats` where each account would need to hold each new token created, like with a vector or something.  I guess this makes it easier to separate accounts from each other instead of getting a giant list of every account with every token symbol in existence.  And easier to know who has to pay for the storage of each new token symbol added.  How did they knew to design it like this in first place? Idk

Answer (score 3):

The scope can be used to narrow down a table list to contain only some fraction of the total entries available.

However, you can also have the best of both worlds if you are willing to pay for the RAM involved.

Why not create a scope called `global`, which contains all of the entries from each individual scope, or alternatively contains a list of each scope name. Then you have a way to loop through several scopes at once as appropriate.